# Should you correct for group characteristics that are correlated to group membership

Tags: covariance, ancova

A little over a year ago, we have collected data by administering neurpsychological tests in several prisons (n=280).  While this data is interesting by itself, we would like to compare these scores to non-detained controls (e.g. “general population”). We have therefore collected data in non-detained controls and tried to recruit a age and education comparable control group. Unfortunately - as these things go – our control group is more highly educated and generally a bit older. I can, of course, correct for age and education in my analyses.

My problem is that a lower education is actually a – well replicated - characteristic of our prison population. For example, when assessing the “highest” finished education, about 1/3rd of the detainees has finished their primary school at best. My control group is a relatively good fit for how the actual population looks (compared to data from the government). Furthermore, education level is generally correlated to neuropsychological test scores.

When assessing the question whether detainees perform differently on neuropsychological testing, should I, or should I not control for education. And how does the interpretation of my data change accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer to your question depend on what the objective of your study is?  Could you provide a clear statement of that objective?